# What is the probability to pass through $1\le m\le n$ vertices of an $n$-sided polygon after $t$ seconds?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, polygons

Suppose a flea is on a vertex of an $n$-sided polygon. It stays still for exactly one second, and then jumps instantly to an adiacent vertex. Let us assume it has no memory of its previous jumps and call $p$ the probability that each second the flea moves clockwise.

> What is the probability $P_{m,t}$ of the flea passing through $1\le m\le n$ vertices after $t$ seconds?

I got interested in this problem after proving that when $p=1/2$ and $n=5$ we have $P_{5,28}>1/2.$

Comment: $P_{m,t}$ is the probability of having passed through all $n$ vertices within the first $t$ seconds?  (I ask because the expression $0 \leq m \leq n$ implies $n+1$ vertices.)  Also, as with all discrete process questions, I must ask: Is $P_{3, 2}$ zero, because we do not count the position at both $T = 0$ and $T = 2$?  Or is it positive because we do?

Comment: @BrianTung When I say "through $1\le m\le n$ vertices" I mean "through $1$, through $2$,...,through $n$ vertices." Regarding the $n+1$ issue, thanks for that, I mysteriously changed my mind while writing that part. So indeed $P_{3,2}$ is positive.

Comment: Of course $P_{1,t}=1$ for all $t$, but that's nevertheless something to account for, when finding the more general $P_{m,t}$.

Comment: @Brian: Any idea?

Comment: I'll think about it.

Comment: I guess this is too computationally expensive, or just not so easy...